# Map Positions in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, software-engineering, coordinates

I am developing an RPG game where there is a main world map, locations such as towns or ruins on that map and buildings in those locations where players can interact to go into. For example, I have a map and my character goes to a local town where there is a inn that I can freely enter and interact in. Once I wish to leave the building, I leave and I'll be at the same position that I had once entered the building from, albeit facing the opposite direction. The one problem that I have with imagining a map system that could be complex like this are the coordinates. Is there a way of accomplishing this with the use of universal coordinates, such as only one x and y position throughout all 3 stages of this map system, or would I need to have 3 coordinates, a Map coordinate system for the world map, a Local coordinate system for the town or ruin and a Temporary coordinate system for when I am in a building? Also, is there something in libGDX that could help out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user data in your tiled map. If you use tiled, you can create object layers and use the objects as spawn and teleport points. For instance, when you exit a cave, you have a spawn point object on your main map set as exit_cave, then set the player position to the exit_cave x and y.

If you're not using a tiled map, I suggest creating a map class and create a hashmap using a string and vector2 for each map you have loaded. That way when you exit a cave, you can easily get the position of the exit from your map to be loaded.

Example.
At init: create instance of map class, Main map and Cave map. In your Main map hashmap, put two objects. <"Cave_enter", new vector2 (0,5)> and <"cave_exit", new vector2 (0,4)>. In your cave map hashmap, put two objects. Main_enter and main_exit.
When you want to change from main to cave, load the cave map and set the player position to Main_enter. When you leave the cave, load the main map and set player position to cave_exit.

Sorry if this is confusing to you. English isn't my first language